# XHR progress not working with uncleared cache in CHROME

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I will try to explain my problem very detailed.

- **NOTE-1**: It is not an issue with small files or whatever. I'm testing it with large files, with slow upload speed network
  throttling...etc
- **NOTE-2**: The progress bar works perfectly in other browser (Tested in edge)
- **NOTE-3**: This issue only occurs in CHROME browser

I'm currently working on a file Uploader by using XHR. Everything works good, files are upload ...etc

I made a progress bar which its working, but only the very first time. (Or when I do CTRL+SHIFT+R), which basically clears the cache. (I have even ticked clear cache in developer mode which is active during testing)

As I said, it works the very first time, however, when I refresh the page, the progress even is not fired. However, `load` event is fired (This event is only fired when the file is fully uploaded)

I tested the code and everything is working fine in Edge browser, I can refresh and progress event is fired correctly, however is not the same for Chrome.

I have read some articles about that content-length must exists in headers and be greater than zero, and it is.

This is my script (The upload part)

```
let uploadFile = () => {
    //... Some other stuffs
    console.log("Upload started")
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    xhr.open("POST", "uploaderServerside.php");
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt){
        console.log("Uploading: " + (Math.round(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100)) + "%");
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log("Upload finished")
    });
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

I hope you can bring me a hand with this issue, thanks for reading and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like chrome has some aggressive caching, you can check the network tab to see if the request is loaded from cache, you will see `(disk cache)` under the size column.

To avoid the cache you can use a cache buster

```
xhr.open("POST", "uploaderServerside.php?_="+(new Date()).getTime());
```

Or you can set Headers on uploaderServerside.php to force the browser to not cache the request like

```
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires: 0
```

Comment: Well, looks like the `script.js` is being loaded from the `disk cache`. I don't know if this causes that the script loads some values from the gc or something similar (I'm not an expert with JS). I tried both methods you mentioned previously and it still being loaded from cache and the issue persists.